# Need to have a search filter option with marker clusters on Leaflet

Tags: javascript, filtering, leaflet.markercluster

I am using csv files to create marker cluster groups. I am trying to allow users the option to search for a specific species and filter the map to display that species' marker clusters. Because of the way that my marker cluster groups are set up I cannot get the search bar to read the csv files to find the column scientific_name which would allow users to search.

I'm new to using Javascript and have been having trouble searching for leaflet functions using csv files. I've tried a different way to create the search bar but it didn't work. I need the variable bullataMarkers to have access to the csv data.

It would also be helpful if there was a way to create a condensed chunk of code for the marker cluster groups so that I can eventually add multiple csv files without having to create a new marker cluster group for each one.

```
// Marker cluster group for Orientallactaga balikunica

var balikunicaMarkers = L.markerClusterGroup();

$.get('Species/Orientallactaga_balikunica.csv', function (csvString) {

  var data = Papa.parse(csvString, { header: true, dynamicTyping: true }).data;
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var Orientallactaga_balikunicaMarker = L.circleMarker([row.latitude, row.longitude], {
      opacity: 1,
      radius: 3,
      color: "#ff1100",
      fillColor: "#ff1100",
      fillOpacity: 1,
    }).bindPopup(row.scientific_name + "<br>" + row.MSB_mammal_number + "<br>" + row.Date);


    balikunicaMarkers.addLayer(Orientallactaga_balikunicaMarker);
  }
});
map.addLayer(balikunicaMarkers)

// Marker cluster group for Orientallactaga bullata

var bullataMarkers = L.markerClusterGroup();

$.get('Species/Orientallactaga_bullata.csv', function (csvString) {

  var data = Papa.parse(csvString, { header: true, dynamicTyping: true }).data;
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var Orientallactaga_bullataMarker = L.circleMarker([row.latitude, row.longitude], {
      opacity: 1,
      radius: 3,
      color: "#FFFFFF",
      fillColor: "#FFFFFF",
      fillOpacity: 1,
    }).bindPopup(row.scientific_name + "<br>" + row.MSB_mammal_number + "<br>" + row.Date);


    bullataMarkers.addLayer(Orientallactaga_bullataMarker);
  }
});
map.addLayer(bullataMarkers)



//Search option



/*


function search() {
  var search =$('#search').val().toLowerCase();

  Orientallactaga_bullataMarker.setFilter(showSpecies);

  function showSpecies(row) {
    return row.scientific_name
    .toLowerCase()
    .indexOf(search) !== -1;
  }
}
*/


$(document).on('keyup', '#search', function () {
  var userInput = this.value;
  bullataMarkers.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    console.log(layer)

    if (layer.rows.scientific_name.indexOf(userInput) > -1) {
      layer.addTo(map);
    } else {
      map.removeLayer(layer);
    }
  }
  )
})
```